# Geocoding API integration with containers and IP whitelisting

Tags: google-api, google-geocoder

I am making requests to the Google Geocoding API within my node project. In production the project is running on Containers (AWS Elastic Container Service) which means the IP address for the service can change automatically - this means that I constantly have to update the IP whitelist in my Google API Key.

IP whitelisting is the only means by which I can secure the API Key. Furthermore, if I don't secure it then the key shortly becomes useless because of unauthorized use from another source.

Is there a practical solution to securing the connection with the Geocoding API from an application running on containers?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: VPS peering is a solution used by other platforms to solve this problem - is anything like this available for the Geocoding API?

Answer (score -1):

When you create your key for the Geocoding API you can simply add no website restrictions.  The security implication is that your key is now usable from anywhere so the import of keeping it safe is a bit higher.

[image]

Comment: I would like to use this solution but with no security my key starts receiving illegitimate activity, sometimes within 24 hours before I've even deployed to the API key to my project!